# Error en Sandbox, Joomla DJClassifieds plugging de Mercado Pago

Tags: mercadopago, joomla3

Buenas de antemano soy algo novato para PHP y esto de implementar keys en sitios webs pero... estoy usando Joomla con la version 3.7.4, DJ Classified 3.4.5

Estoy tratando de implemetar en el sitio que estoy construyendo de clasificados con el plugin de Mercado Pago, revise el contenido PHP de este y parece estar correcto, ingreso los datos de cliente y key y cuando le doy click al boton de pagar me indica: 
0
couldn't connect to host
The page you are looking for does not exist or an other error occurred.
Go back or head over to the home page to choose a new direction.

No quiero hacer spam poniendo mi sitio aqui, pero si alguien que me ayude le doy los datos que necesite y de algun modo le adjunto el plugging para que me lo revise.

Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tambien aprovecha y mira [por que no somos soporte de mercado libre](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%C3%A9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%C3%B1%C3%ADa-favorita)